# Search for value of data attribute with multiple value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with data attribute with multiple value.

I have a form with steps. In first step i have a node:

```
<div id="step-0">
 <input id="nd1" type="radio" name="ordernode" value="val1">
 <input id="nd2" type="radio" name="ordernode" value="val2">
</div>
```

if user sets first value, another steps with `data-node nd1` (to this id) will have `class activated`.

```
<div id="step-1" class="step" data-node="nd1">
 Step 1
</div>
<div id="step-3" class="step" data-node="nd1">
 Step 3
</div>
```

So for another node. But there are steps that belong to `node 1` and `node 2`. I don't want to create **same steps** fore `node 1` and `node 2`, and that's why i try to add in `data-node` attribute 2 values like

```
<div id="step-4" class="step" data-node="nd1,nd2">
    Step 4
</div>
```

This step belongs to `node 1` and `node 2`.

Without multiple value of `data-node` attribute in JQuery i have

```
var nodeActive = $(this).find('input').attr('id');
$(this).parents('.sof_body').find('[data-node="'+nodeActive+'"]').addClass('activated');
```

It works fine and fast, i have no problem. But with multiple value i must search in each step `data-node` attribute and try to find id of node in string like

```
var nodeActive = $(this).find('input').attr('id');
$(this).parents('.sof_body').find('.step').each(function(){
  var nodesBe = $(this).data('node');
  if (nodesBe.indexOf(''+nodeActive+'') >= 0){
      $(this).addClass('activated');
  }
});
```

This function also works, but slower, than first, that cause many problems with another functions, that calls after this function.

My question is, is there another way to realize search function for multiple value to make it without `each function`, or to make it fast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trim down the targeted element by using [Attribute Contains Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) and for exact match use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
var nodeActive = $(this).find('input').attr('id');
$(this).closest('.sof_body').find('.step[data-node*=' + nodeActive + ']').filter(function () {
    return $(this).data('node').split(',').indexOf(nodeActive) > -1;
}).addClass('activated');
```